# Compute which of a finite number of integrals is minimal (not interested in the actual value of the integral)

Tags: sampling, optimization, monte-carlo, extreme-value, numerical-integration

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space;
- $f:E\to[0,\infty)^3$ be a bounded Bochner integrable function on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ and $p:=\alpha_1f_1+\alpha_2f_2+\alpha_3f_3$ for some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\ge0$ with $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=1$ and $$\int p\:{\rm d}\lambda\in(0,\infty)\tag1$$
- $I$ be a finite nonempty set
- $r:(I\times E)\times E$ be the density of a Markov kernel with source $(I\times E,2^I\otimes\mathcal E)$ and target $(E,\mathcal E)$ with $$E_1:=\{p>0\}\subseteq\{r((i,x),\;\cdot\;)>0\}\;\;\;\text{for all }i\in I\tag2$$

> Fix $x\in E$. I want to find the index $i\in I$ minimizing $$\sigma_i:=\lambda_i\left|f-\frac{\lambda_if}{\lambda_i(E_1)}\right|^2=\lambda_i(E_1)\operatorname E_i\left[\left|f-\operatorname E_i[f]\right|^2\right],$$ where $$\lambda_i:=\frac1{r((i,x),\;\cdot\;)}\left.\lambda\right|_{E_1}$$ and $\operatorname E_i$ is the expectation wrt $$\operatorname P_i:=\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_i(E_1)}$$ for $i\in I$.

I'm not interested in the value $\sigma_i$ itself.

Currently I'm estimating each $\sigma_i$ using Monte Carlo integration and then compute the minimum. However, this is extremely slow.

I'm not familiar with this kind of problem and hence this might be nonsensical, but note that if $Y_i$ is an $(E,\mathcal E)$-valued random variable with $Y_i\sim r((i,x),\;\cdot\;)\lambda$, then \begin{equation}\begin{split}&\sigma_i=\operatorname E\left[1_{E_1}(Y_i)\frac{|f(Y_i)|^2}{\left|r((i,x),Y_i)\right|^2}\right]\\&\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;-\left(\operatorname E\left[1_{E_1}(Y_i)\frac1{\left|r((i,x),Y_i)\right|^2}\right]\right)^{-1}\left|\operatorname E\left[1_{E_1}(Y_i)\frac{f(Y_i)}{\left|r((i,x),Y_i)\right|^2}\right]\right|^2\end{split}\tag3\end{equation} for all $i\in I$. So, we might approximate $\sigma_i$ by an independent identically distributed process $\left(Y_i^{(n)}\right)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $Y_i^{(1)}\sim r((i,x),\;\cdot\;)\lambda$ via $$A_i^{(n)}-\frac1{B_i^{(n)}}\left|C_i^{(n)}\right|^2\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\sigma_i\;\;\;\text{almost surely},\tag4$$ where \begin{align}A_i^{(n)}:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1_{E_1}f}{\left|r((i,x),\;\cdot\;)\right|^2}\left(Y_i^{(n)}\right),\\B_i^{(n)}:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1_{E_1}}{\left|r((i,x),\;\cdot\;)\right|^2}\left(Y_i^{(n)}\right),\\C_i^{(n)}:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left|\frac{1_{E_1}f}{r((i,x),\;\cdot\;)}\right|^2\left(Y_i^{(n)}\right)\end{align} for $n\in\mathbb N$, for all $i\in I$.

Currently I'm using $(4)$ to estimate $\sigma_i$ and then compute the minimum among the estimates. But this is extreme slowly and might even be erroneous.

Comment: This problem seems to be covered by [stochastic approximation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation) such as Robbins-Monro and Kiefer-Wolfowitz.

Comment: @Xi'an Can you elaborate on that? I'm not familiar with stochastic approximation algorithms, but at first glance it seems like we would need some kind of differentiability.

Comment: @Xi'an Do you think my problem fits the problem in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation#Application_in_Stochastic_Optimization? My $\theta$ would belong to $\mathcal X$ and hence would be discrete.

Comment: There are extensions of the basic SA algorithms to discrete spaces, see https://www.jhuapl.edu/SPSA/ and some of the articles mentioned therein.

Comment: Maybe multi-armed bandits, then?

Comment: @jbowman Maybe I'm not getting how you intend to describe my problem such that it fits into the setting described in the references (for example https://www.jhuapl.edu/SPSA/PDF-SPSA/Hill_TechDig05.pdf), but it seems like $I\ni i\mapsto C_i$ would need to be convex.

Comment: @Xi'an I guess it's cause I'm not familiar with the problems you're referring to, but I hardly see that my problem fits into their settings. I've asked a similiar question for a particular instance of this setting on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/355334/compute-which-of-a-finite-number-of-integrals-is-minimal. Maybe you get a better understanding of it, if we you take a look.

Comment: Bayesian optimization also works on discrete values...

Comment: @ItamarMushkin Can you elaborate on that or provide an answer?

Comment: You're right; I was reflexively following up on @Xi'an 's initial comment and your observation that you have a discrete problem, rather than really addressing your question - my mistake.

Comment: @jbowman Thanks for clarifying.