# Minimize asymptotic variance of fintely many estimates

Tags: sampling, optimization, monte-carlo, extreme-value, numerical-integration

Let

- $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space;
- $f:E\to[0,\infty)^3$ be a bounded function with integrable Euclidean norm on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ and $p:=\alpha_1f_1+\alpha_2f_2+\alpha_3f_3$ for some $\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3\ge0$ with $\alpha_1+\alpha_2+\alpha_3=1$ and $$c:=\int p\:{\rm d}\lambda\in(0,\infty)\tag1$$
- $\mu:=p\lambda$
- $I\subseteq$ be a finite nonempty set
- $r_i$ be a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ with $$E_1:=\{p>0\}\subseteq\{r_i>0\}\tag2$$ for $i\in I$
- $w_i:E\to[0,1]$ be $\mathcal E$-measurable for $i\in I$ with $$\{p>0\}\subseteq\left\{\sum_{i\in I}w_i=1\right\}\tag3$$

> I'm running the Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with target distribution $\mu$ and use the generated chain to estimate $\lambda g$ for $\mathcal E$-measurable $g:E\to[0,\infty)^3$ with $\{p=0\}\subseteq\{g=0\}$ and $\lambda|g|<\infty$. The asymptotic variance of my estimate is given by $$\sigma^2(g)=\sum_{i\in I}(\mu w_i)\int_{E_1}\frac{\left|g-\frac pc\lambda g\right|^2}{r_i}\:{\rm d}\lambda.\tag4$$ Given a finite system $H\subseteq\mathcal E$ with $\lambda(H)\in(0,\infty)$ for all $H\in\mathcal H$, I want to choose the $w_i$ such that $$\max_{H\in\mathcal H}\sigma^2(1_Hf)\tag5$$ is as small as possible.

It's easy to see that, for fixed $g$, $(3)$ is minimized by choosing $w_i\equiv 1$ for the $i\in I$ which minimizes $\int_{E_1}\frac{\left|g-\frac pc\lambda g\right|^2}{r_i}\:{\rm d}\lambda$ and $w_j\equiv 0$ for all other $j\in I\setminus\{i\}$.

So, my idea is to bound $(5)$ by something which doesn't depend on $\mathcal H$ anymore. Maybe we can bound it by the "variance" of $f$ using the fact that the $\operatorname E[X]$ is minimizing $x\mapsto\operatorname E\left[\left\|x-X\right\|\right]$.

I'm not sure if this is sensible, but maybe it's easier to consider $\sigma^2(g_H)$ instead of $\sigma^2(1_Hf)$, where $g_H:=1_H\left(f-\frac{\lambda(1_Hf)}{\lambda(H)}\right)$. By the aforementioned idea we obtain $$\sigma^2(g_H)\le\int_{E_1}\frac{|f|^2}{r_i}\:{\rm d}\lambda-\frac1{\theta_i}\left|\int_{E_1}\frac f{r_i}\:{\rm d}\lambda\right|^2\tag5,$$ where $\theta_i=\int_{E_1}\frac1{r_i}\:{\rm d}\lambda$. Now we could estimate the right-hand side of $(5)$ using Monte Carlo integration and compute the index $i$ for which this estimate is minimal. Is this a good idea or can we do better?

Comment: The way this question is written makes it almost impossible to parse. I can't imagine a reasonable situation in which $f$ being Bochner-integrable instead of just integrable is relevant, but that's just the tip of the iceberg. The way in which all of the relevant functions and measures are defined at the start of the question is completely opaque. It would be much simpler to just say something like 'here are some distributions, they live on this space, they have this density', rather than worrying about measurability, pushforwards, and so on.

Comment: @πr8 Well, Bochner-integrability is the notion we need, since $f$ is vector-valued. And the pushforwards might be important to transform the integrals. I've asked this question without the detailed the description of the objects before, but didn't receive any answer.

Comment: $f$ maps into $\mathbf{R}^3$ - I don't think that there's any risk of being misunderstood if you just said that $f$ was integrable. Anyways, the question is hard enough to solve if $f$ is scalar-valued, so let's not get hung up on that. You can first try to solve the case where $|I|=2$; hopefully this can de-clutter things a bit, and should be indicative of the general case. Secondly, are the $q_i$ known explicitly, or can they only be accessed by simulation? Thirdly, is there a particular motivation for using this 'Wrapped Gaussian' $\Psi$ instead of drawing uniformly from a ball around $x$?

Comment: As a preliminary comment, it seems likely to be quite difficult, as you don't have access to $\lambda_j$ in particularly concrete ways, and so you will have to estimate the $c_j$ in some form or another. You can maybe find ways of reducing the variance of your estimators here and there, but you're probably not going to end up with an analytic solution anywhere

Comment: @πr8 Okay, I've completely rewritten the question, simplified the problem and provided more details. Hopefully it's more accessible now.

Comment: I would hardly call this a complete rewrite; you haven't addressed a single point the other commenter has made in any meaningful fashion, AFAICT.   For example, if the responders must be limited just to people who actually know what Bochner-integrability is *because otherwise they have no hope of answering the question*, as opposed to just understanding that $f$ is integrable, you aren't likely to get many responses.

Comment: @jbowman Well, in this case it simply means that the Euclidean norm $|f|$ of $f$ is integrable. I've rephrased that in the question.